# Javascript - Insert code segments at multiple locations

Tags: javascript

**What I like to do is**:  If any of the 3 optional fields is filled out, a chunk of code(row) will be inserted into the source code(table) and then the entire code will be outputted.

**My issue right now is**:  If more than one of the fields is entered, only the last input is inserted.  I need all of them inserted.  I suspect that the "code =" statement needs to be changed/relocated but not sure how to go about it.  I'm a beginner in javascript, so please keep your answers as basic as you can.  Thank you!!

html:

```
<input id="input1" onChange="update()">
<input id="input2" onChange="update()">
<input id="input3" onChange="update()">
```

javascript:

```
var source = '<table><!--PlaceHolder1--><!--PlaceHolder2--><!--PlaceHolder3--></table>';
var insert = '<tr><td>InsertText</td></tr>';

function update(){

if(document.getElementById("input1").value != ""){

  var x = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var y = insert.replace("InsertText", x );         
  code = source.replace("<!--PlaceHolder1-->", y );
  }

if(document.getElementById("input2").value != ""){

  var x = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  var y = insert.replace("InsertText", x );         
  code = source.replace("<!--PlaceHolder2-->", y );
  }

if(document.getElementById("input3").value != ""){

  var x = document.getElementById("input3").value;
  var y = insert.replace("InsertText", x );         
  code = source.replace("<!--PlaceHolder3-->", y );
  }

}

document.write(code);
```

Comment: Please don't use `document.write`. If a book told you to use that, you need a better book that will teach you about DOM manipulation.

Comment: try changing `code = source.replace...`  to `code += source.replace...`

Comment: It looks like you're just overwriting yourself because there is no clear distinction between the three, especially when it comes to something like the `code` variable.

Comment: @slime Can you give me an example?  But the 'else if' condition only executes if the first 'if' condition is not met though, isn't it?

Comment: @JLRishe I'm just using that to demonstrate that 'code' is what I need outputed, you can replace that with alert(), whatever you like.

Comment: Just re-examine your `code` variable. It's being set on the first if, then you're setting it again on the second, and setting it again on the third. The reason you're only seeing the last one is because the last one is setting it. You need to create a variable for each one, or set the information differently...like an array or something.

Comment: @xtrakBandit I'll try that.  If anybody can give an example, that would be very helpful.

Comment: It's a bit unclear, what exactly you want to add to the page. In the text you say you want to add a row to an existing(?) table,  but the code adds a whole new table. Which you actually need?

Comment: Doesn't JLRish'es answer do exactly what you want? Or do you need to create the table dynamically?

Comment: [Any help](http://jsfiddle.net/n2nt2g5y/1/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're losing the result of the first replace, which is in the variable "code" because you're overwriting it with the contents of "source" on subsequent replaces.

Instead of this:

```
code = source.replace("<!--PlaceHolder2-->", y );
```

Try this:

```
code = code.replace("<!--PlaceHolder2-->", y );
```

And I think you'll get what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you're trying to do this with string replacement. You should be using proper DOM manipulation. This will also allow you to clean up your code a lot:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function update(e) {
    var target = e.target,
        num = target.getAttribute("data-num"),
        td = document.querySelectorAll("#theTable td")[num - 1];
   
    td.textContent = target.value;
    td.parentNode.style.display = "table-row";
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i += 1) {
    document.getElementById("input" + i).onchange = update;
  }
}
```

```css
  #theTable tr {
display: none;
  }
```

```html
<input id="input1" data-num="1">
<input id="input2" data-num="2">
<input id="input3" data-num="3">
<table id="theTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll have to look into this.